# SettingWithCopyWarning using datetime index

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

First of all I know there is some topics who have the same title but they are not asking exactly the same question so I thought I will write my own.

I have a datetime index dataframe which works pretty well.

But I try to implement some new columns by using for loops, and it give me the above message :

> SettingWithCopyWarning:  A value is trying to be set on a copy of a
> slice from a DataFrame

I of course googled it and figured out it was something call chain indexing.
The code I made still work, but I understand this was not the best way to do it so here am I for advice.

One of the examples is when I try to create new columns, indicating the part of the day.
Here is the code I used :

```
def get_part_of_day(hour):
    return (
        "morning" if 5 <= hour <= 11
        else
        "afternoon" if 12 <= hour <= 17
        else
        "evening" if 18 <= hour <= 22
        else
        "night"
    )

df['part_of_day'] = df['hour'].map(get_part_of_day)

df['morning']=""
for i in range (len(df)):
    if  df['part_of_day'][i]=='morning':
        df['morning'][i]=1
    else :
        df['morning'][i]=0

df['afternoon']=""
for i in range (len(df)):
    if  df['part_of_day'][i]=='afternoon':
        df['afternoon'][i]=1
    else :
        df['afternoon'][i]=0
        
df['evening']=""
for i in range (len(df)):
    if  df['part_of_day'][i]=='evening':
        df['evening'][i]=1
    else :
        df['evening'][i]=0
        
df['night']=""
for i in range (len(df)):
    if  df['part_of_day'][i]=='night':
        df['night'][i]=1
    else :
        df['night'][i]=0
```

I get the warning message when I am trying any df['example'][i]=number

I saw the documentation says to use .loc or .at but as I use a datetime index it's not really easy to do...

Does anyone have any solution for this?

Have a nice day all

Answer (score 2):

Replace all your:

```
         df['morning'][i]=1
```

To:

```
         df.loc['morning', i]=1
```

For all `df[<col name>][i]` assignments.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but when I try this I get an error message : "ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis"

Comment: @SonnePer That's not a problem with my code, I solved your current problem, that is with another problem in your code.